# Can't Unit Test: $_SESSION empties before each test is ran

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I can't unit test my code.

$_SESSION clears every time the next test is run. 
When I run testStartProductSession() my object adds some data to the $_SESSION variable. But when I run the next test method ( testSessionIdIsKept() ) the $_SESSION is empty again.

Looks like $_SESSION becomes local variable when unit testing.

I don't know what else to do. Please check the output bellow:

```
// session_start() on bootrap.php;

class MC_Session_ProductTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @return MC_Session_Product
     */
    public function getObject()
    {
        // make getInstance() return new instance instead of singleton instance
        MC_Session_Product::$isUnityTest = true;
        $object = MC_Session_Product::getInstance();
        $object->getWsClient()->setServerListUrl(SERVER_LIST_URL);
        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * All tests pass
     * @depends testSetParam
     */
    public function testStartProductSession()
    {
        $developerId = PARAM_DEVELOPER_ID;
        $productCode = PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE;
        $productVersion = PARAM_PRODUCT_VERSION;
        $platform = PARAM_PLATAFORM;
        $deviceType = PARAM_DEVICE_TYPE;
        $locale = PARAM_LOCALE;

        try {
            $object = $this->getObject();
            $object->startSession($developerId, $productCode, $productVersion,
                                  $platform, $deviceType, $locale);
            $this->assertTrue($object->sessionStarted());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->fail('Fail to start session: ' . $object->getLastUrl());
        }

        echo "\$_SESSION in testStartProductSession(): ", print_r($_SESSION, 1);
        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * Test fails because $_SESSION is empty again
     * @depends testStartProductSession
     */
    public function testSessionIdIsKept(MC_Session_Product $lastObject)
    {
        echo "\$_SESSION in testSessionIdIsKept(): ", print_r($_SESSION, 1);
        $object = $this->getObject();
        // fails
        $this->assertTrue($lastObject->sessionStarted());
        $this->assertTrue($object->sessionStarted());
        $this->assertEquals($lastObject->getSessionId(), $object->getSessionId());
        return $object;
    }
}

/* ###### Output


$_SESSION in testStartProductSession():
Array
(
    [__MC] => Array
        (
            [MC_Session_Product] => Array
                (
                    [keyOne] => 'valueOne'
                    [sessionId] => 'someId'
                )

        )

)
$_SESSION in testSessionIdIsKept():
Array
(
)

*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit resets all global variables--including `$_SESSION`--to their starting values before each test method. You can disable this for a test case by overriding the `$backupGlobals` instance property to `false`. This does not work from the `setUp()` method.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $backupGlobals = FALSE;

    // ...
}
```

See [Global Variables and PHPUnit](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/797-Global-Variables-and-PHPUnit.html) for further details.

Comment: Kudos! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making $_SESSION a dependency for your unit tests, you should parameterise the parts of the session that each function needs. Then you can mock the parameters in your unit test easily. Doing this the current way you're trying is too difficult and makes your code less testable. This will require changing your current code, but it will improve your code and make things more testable.

Comment: Well, this is the first project i try to unit test. I don't have the faintest idea of how I could replace $_SESSION (an array) by a mock **object**. I can't reference that. Do you have any code sample that achieves that goal? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume there is a method which is called before every test. You can set up the cookie there. In java you have the annotation @Before.

Comment: In PHPUnit you create a method named `setUp()`--the same as the non-annotation way in JUnit.